# Are these singular chain complexes possible?

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I am currently learning singular homology and one question gives these two chain complexes:

$A: 0 \rightarrow 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$

$B: 0 \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow \mathbb{Z} \rightarrow 0$

I am asked to compute a set of maps $A \rightarrow B$ and a set of chain homotopy classes of chain maps. I am puzzled by this question, because with singular complexes, even a single point set has $C_n$ isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}$ for all $n$, so I don't see how we can have chain complexes that look like the ones above.
I feel like I am missing something here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The concept of a [chain complex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_complex) can sit independent of topology: it's a sequence of a abelian groups
\[
\cdots \xrightarrow{d_{n + 2}} A_{n + 1} \xrightarrow{d_{n - 1}} A_n \xrightarrow{d_n} A_{n - 1} \xrightarrow{d_{n - 1}} \cdots
\]
 such that $d_n \circ d_{n - 1} = 0$ for all $n$. So the question makes sense. But complexes like yours can certainly arise when computing [simplicial homology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simplicial_homology); for example, $S^1$ has a $\Delta$-complex structure (see [Hatcher's book](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html)) for which the corresponding chain complex would look like your $B$.

Comment: When I first saw this question, I thought the way you explained above, but I guess what really confuses me is the 'chain homotopy classes of chain maps' part. Doesn't a chain map depend on topology?

Comment: @Barum Chain maps are described later in [the article I mentioned](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chain_complex#Chain_maps). A [chain homotopy](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Homotopy_category_of_chain_complexes) is again an algebraic definition, although the motivation surely comes from topology.